# defer() method returning unknown interaction error

Tags: python, error-handling, discord.py, bots

**Issue**

My slash commands return `404 Not Found (error code: 10062): Unknown interaction` when I run them. I do have them deferred as:

```
@bot.tree.command(name="evaluate")
async def evaluate(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    await interaction.response.defer(ephemeral=True)
    await asyncio.sleep(10)
    await interaction.followup.send("Command works")
```

for example.

However, when I run my commands, it raises the following error:

```
File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/discord/app_commands/commands.py", line 862, in _do_call
    return await self._callback(interaction, **params)  # type: ignore
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/container/bot.py", line 282, in evaluate
    await interaction.response.defer(ephemeral=False, thinking=True)
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/discord/interactions.py", line 636, in defer
    await adapter.create_interaction_response(
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/discord/webhook/async_.py", line 218, in request
    raise NotFound(response, data)
discord.errors.NotFound: 404 Not Found (error code: 10062): Unknown interaction
```

This happens mostly in one command, but at the very end. The entire command works fine but the bot doesn't send the final confirmation response `await interaction.followup.send()` and instead throws the above error. (Edited paragraph)

**Reason for posting:**

I don't really think I'm making an error with the code itself, which is why I'd like some insight as to why this is or may be happening. I also posted this in case someone else in the future encounters the same issue, since I couldn't find similar or same questions asked here on SO.

Comment: It may be related to authentication and the server is returning 404 for unauthenticated/unauthorized requests. Do you have a way to test the authentication alone?

Comment: @luxcem My apologies, but I don't quite understand what you mean by that. Could you elaborate?

Comment: It seems you are using a module to communicate with a discord server, the module return a 404 error (it's an http error). A 404 error is usually related to non existing url, but sometimes servers returns 404 for unauthorized requests. I'm assuming you need some authentication to be able to use the discord api. Are you sure this is setup correctly?

Comment: @luxcem As far as authentication for using the API goes, I can only think of the token that Discord uses to identify my bot.

Comment: Make sure you are correctly identified with this token and have access to the server you are using. Otherwise I cannot help you more with only this.

Comment: Yeah. That's all in order.

Comment: Does your client have the correct scopes specified on invite and in the discord developer portal?

Comment: @Libra yeah, it does. Like I said, the entire command works as intended, but the final response is never sent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Posted this on the discord.py official Discord Server and got an answer.

If a 404 Not Found error appears even after deferring, it means that it took too long for the `defer()` to execute. Or in other words, your `await interaction.response.defer()` is running after 3 seconds have passed and the API request has already been terminated.

Credit: SolsticeShard on the discord.py Discord.

The solution was to run `defer()` much earlier up the code block. That ensures that the interaction is deferred before the 3s time limit has passed.

Comment: I'm still having this same issue. I'm deferring at the first instruction.. I can't defer any sooner. Can you post the link for the discussion you had at the official Discord Server?

Comment: Is deferring the literal first line you write under the program? Because you can defer first, then do everything else in the command.

Comment: I understand that one can only defer within the command context, something like:
```@bot.tree.event(name="my_command")
async def my_command(interaction):
   interaction.defer()```
Can one defer any sooner?

Comment: Bruv, you've made a `@bot.tree.event()`. Not a `@bot.tree.command()`

Comment: I did `bot.tree.command` indeed, I just wrote that from memory. Apologies for the inaccuracy.. The point I'm stressing is 'how soon can one defer?'

Comment: Ah, I'm afraid I'm not expert enough to answer this (or I do know the answer but don't have enough context). The discord.py Discord is quite active, you can ask them there. Here's the link: https://discord.gg/dpy

Comment: But yeah @cavalcantelucas, if you defer from the get-go, that's as early as it can be done.